# Redshift copy from json "Statement failed to complete execution" with empty stl_load_errors

Tags: amazon-s3, bigdata, amazon-redshift

I have json.gz files in S3. The size of files form several kilos up to 300MB (compressed).

Trying to load all of them into Redshift with  next command:

```
copy my_table from 's3://my-bucket/'
access_key_id 'qqq'
secret_access_key 'qqq'
dateformat 'auto'
timeformat 'epochsecs'
COMPUPDATE ON
gzip json 's3://another-bucket/json_paths.json'
```

**my_table** has fields that were specified with **json_paths.json**. 
I tried several times to do it and **only once** it get loaded completely, without any changes in s3 bucket and table structure. Now its always stopping on about 300M of records instead of 800M of total of them and showing **Statement failed to complete execution**.

```
SELECT * FROM stl_load_errors
```

Shows me 0 records, hence I have no info about what happened.

Cluster was from 4 to 8 nodes and was succeed on 6 nodes but only once from several tries, and even on 8 it fails later (magic!)
Total uncompressed data size is about 130GB so cluster is much much larger that it.

I have no doubt that data is ok! 
Also tried to load by prefix (files has prefix, something like "data_2016_01_01.gz", "data_2017_12_17.gz") so I can load year by year, for instance ,and it works properly!

The question is:

where to see the reason why it fails, if **stl_load_errors** empty